# Como implementar um navigation drawer que suporta variações da appbar nos fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Estou tentando implementar um navigation drawer que suporte 2 variações da appbar. O projeto tem uma atividade única e fragmentos de destino de nível superior: alguns usarão a toolbar padrão e outros usarão CollapsingToolbarLayout com um imageView interno. No entanto, o aplicativo não navega para os destinos clicando nos itens da gaveta.

[Na documentação para suportar variações da appbar](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#support_app_bar_variations), ta dizendo o seguinte:

> A lógica de configuração de navegação é a mesma para ambos os fragmentos, exceto que você deve chamar **`setupWithNavController()` de dentro do método `onViewCreated()` de cada fragmento**, em vez de inicializá-los a partir da atividade[...]

Mas na parte da [implementação do navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) só diz assim:

> Em seguida, em sua classe de atividade principal, chame **`setupWithNavController()` do método `onCreate()` de sua atividade principal**, conforme mostrado abaixo[...]

Já tentei fazer as adaptações necessárias, mas to perdendo alguma coisa. Aqui está o que tentei pela última vez usando o template de navigation drawer do Android Studio:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`content_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Teste.PopupOverlay" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_gallery.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:expanded="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="152dp"
            app:contentScrim="@color/purple_500"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleCollapseMode="scale">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

`mobile_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.devreis.ofertas.teste.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.devreis.ofertas.teste.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />
</navigation>
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout by lazy { binding.drawerLayout }
    val appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration by lazy {
        AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery
            ), drawerLayout
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

`HomeFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.MainActivity
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.textHome.text = "Home fragment"
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navController = findNavController()
        val appBarConfiguration = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).appBarConfiguration
        binding.toolbar.apply {
            (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity, navController, appBarConfiguration)
            setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

`GalleryFragment.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.MainActivity
import com.devreis.ofertas.teste.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.textGallery.text = "Gallery fragment"
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navController = findNavController()
        val appBarConfiguration = (requireActivity() as MainActivity).appBarConfiguration
        binding.toolbar.apply {
            (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity, navController, appBarConfiguration)
            setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

`build.gradle:app`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.devreis.ofertas.teste'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devreis.ofertas.teste"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
}
```

O app roda sem erros, mas ao clicar nos itens da gaveta nada acontece.
Preciso que a navegação aconteça e a barra superior reaja mostrando os nomes de cada fragmento e exibindo a imagem no fragmento usando o imageView do CollapsingToolbarLayout.